# Keyboard Paypal has two Z instead Z and Y

Tags: android, paypal

I am developing an app which contains `PayPal sdk`. The problem is for some `HTC`devices (for example: `HTC One S Android 4.1`), the keyboard has two `Z` instead `Z` and `Y`. This happens when the language is `English (Germany)`. Does someone know where is the problem?.Thanks!

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Well, for German, it's a QWERTZ layout, usually, AFAIK. Are you certain it's not a "Y" where the "Z" usually is? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Yes of course. I have already checked typping and both keys are Z

Comment: OK, just making sure you weren't just going by second-hand info. Is that with the HTC's default keyboard?

Comment: Sorry I don`t know what you mean. This only happens when the keyboard is opened with PayPal